# Not able to connect to MySql database while running the web application in JBOSS

Tags: java, mysql, jboss

I have a web application which runs successfully in Tomcat server and it uses MySql database. Now, I am trying to run it on JBOSS 7, but the DB connection is not happening. No error in `C:\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\log\server.log` file. Not sure where else can I see some error messages.

**My standalone.xml**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/Matix" pool-name="Matix" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Matix</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

**My module.xml under the path: `C:\jboss-eap-6.2\modules\com\mysql\main` (Also, not sure if the path is correct) **

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
   <resources>
     <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar"/>

   </resources>

   <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.api"/>
      <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

I put `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` under the path `C:\jboss-eap-6.2\modules\com\mysql\main`

I have not done any changes in my web.xml and my JDBC Connection code. Are those required?

What else I am missing? Please help.

### EDIT

** part of Java Code **

```
public class LoginAction implements ServletResponseAware {
    public String login() {
            String result_type_Is = "";
            result_type_Is = this.checkAuthorization(con);
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            out.write(result_type_Is);
    }
}

private String checkAuthorization(Connection con) {

        try {
            // Checking DB Authentication
            // Returns SUCCESS or WRONG 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //..........
            return FAIL;
        } finally {
            // Closing all connections
        }
        return result;
    }
```

**JS Code**

```
var display = login_request.responseText;
if (display == "SUCCESS") {
// redirect to home page
}
else{
//Show DB conn failure msg
}
```

Comment: If you get no errors, then how can you claim that "no connection is made"? On what basis do you make that statement?

Comment: My login page calls LoginAction class, which tries to connect to MySQL database. In case of any exceptions, it will return null. And in javascript, in case of null it prints "Failed to connect to DB". I am getting this message whenever I try to run my application in JBOSS. But, from Eclipse and Tomcat, it works fine. Do I need to change anything in my code? Will this approach not work in JBOSS?

Comment: <action name="loginaction" class="com.app.action.LoginAction"
   method="login"> 
</action>

Comment: Added Java and Javascript code

Comment: I am pretty sure that somewhere you are throwing away exceptions, possibly in that checkAuthorization() method you neglect to post.

Comment: checkAuthorization() method checks the validity of the user credentials with the DB and returns SUCCESS or FAIL based on the result. Added code in the main question.

Comment: There you go. log that exception you catch to see what is the truth.